# SQL, How to add the name of a a manger next to his employee's

Tags: sql, database, database-design

[image: this is my diagram]

so I just need to make an inquiry with the employee's and I want the manager's name for each to be shown
 each emp is in a dept and each dept has a name and manager's id which is same as his employee id

Comment: Please specify what you tried and which problems you faced, so we can help you. You'll probably get good answers if you show that you put some effort into solving the problem at hand. Also have a look at [ask].

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. Please also read & act on hits googling 'stackexhange homework'.

Comment: Please use enough words, references & sentences to be clear. Don't try to cram everything into one sentence. Please use standard English including punctuation. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you close.

```
select 
  e.first_name
  , e.last_name 
  , m.first_name as 'manager first name'
  , m.last_name as 'manager last name'
  , d.name
from employee e
  inner join dept d 
    left outer join employee m on d.manager_id = m.id
  on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
```